# labels in Dynkin-diagram package

Tags: symbols

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}


\begin{document}
 
$\mathbb{K}$ can be displayed and so can \dynkin[labels = \theta] A1 
but replacing $\theta$ by $\mathbb{K}$ (both without dollar signs in the actual command) yields an error what goes wrong and how do you fix it?

Thanks a lot,
Hercule
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: thanks very much

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with a 2021 TeX installation. You could try with `\dynkin[label,labelmacro/.code={\mathbb{K}}] A1` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that with the latest version of the package (which should be included in a 2021 TeX installation, you should actually be able to write `\dynkin[labels={\mathbb{K}}] A1` (even without curly brackets).

As an alternative approach, you can try using the `label macro` option like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}
 
$\mathbb{K}$ can be displayed and so can \dynkin[label,label
macro/.code={\mathbb{K}}] A1 .

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/dynkin-diagrams/dynkin-diagrams.pdf) at "8. Label subscripts".

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\dynkin[labels={K},label macro/.code={\mathbb{#1}}] A1 
\end{document}
```

[image]

which will put all labels in to the mathematics blackboard font; I suppose that is probably what you want. But I admit I need to work out why your first guess:

```
\dynkin[labels={\mathbb{K}}] A1
```

doesn't work. I can confirm that it doesn't work with the last version of the dynkin-diagrams package.

Comment: The latter *does* work with dynkin-diagrams 2021/04/04 for me (using PDFLaTeX).

Comment: Thanks both for your help, I could not split bounty points so gave it to Jasper as he was first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, and I'm not sure if this is relevant enough but I thought I'd add something in case someone as silly as me runs into the same issue.

If you have the `underscore` package loaded you will run into the "Missing number, treated as zero" error when you use a label like `\alpha_1` in the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}
$ \dynkin[Coxeter, gonality=3, label, labels={\alpha_1,2}] I{} $
\end{document}
```

will result in

[image: 1]

rather than the following, if `\usepackage{underscore}` is removed

[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: With use of recent version of MiKTeX I can't reproduce your result.  Try to upgrade your LaTeX installation. BTW. your answer is more like to new question than answer.

Comment: With the most recent TeXLive, I can't reproduce this error.